# aggregate-initializable tuple like data structure

Tags: c++, stdtuple, aggregate-initialization

I want to store multiple non-movable types in a single variable.

At the very first, I have tried std::tuple at the very first, but it fails.

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct No {
    No(T){}
    No(const No &) = delete;
    No(No &&) = delete;
};

struct Handmade {
    No<int> a;
    No<double> b;
    No<char> c;
};

template<typename T>
auto no() -> No<T> { return No<T>(T()); }

auto main() -> int
{
    Handmade h = {no<int>(), no<double>(), no<char>()}; // good
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(no<int>(), no<double>(), no<char>()); // fails
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `Handmade` type can be initialized through aggregate initialization.
However, `std::tuple` is not aggregate-initialzable, it doesn't work.

Since it should be variadic, I cannot write such type `Handmade` for my purpose.

Is it possible to implement such variadic tepmlate data structure in current C++ standard or is there any workaround?

Comment: Perhaps `std::tuple<No<int>, No<double>, No<char>> tuple{1, 2.3, '4'};`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No<T> is just an example and I only know factory function such as no<T>().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write your own aggregate tuple like this:

```
template <int I, typename T>
struct MyTupleElem
{
    T value{};
    template <int J> requires(I == J)       T &get()       {return value;}
    template <int J> requires(I == J) const T &get() const {return value;}
};

template <typename T, typename ...P>
struct MyTupleHelper;
template <int ...I, typename ...P>
struct MyTupleHelper<std::integer_sequence<int, I...>, P...>
    : MyTupleElem<I, P>...
{
    using MyTupleElem<I, P>::get...;
};

template <typename ...P>
struct MyTuple : MyTupleHelper<std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(P)>, P...> {};

template <typename ...P>
MyTuple(P &&...) -> MyTuple<std::decay_t<P>...>;
```

```
template <typename T>
struct No
{
    T value;
    No(T value) : value(value) {}
    No(const No &) = delete;
    No(No &&) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
No<T> no(T t) {return No<T>(t);}

int main()
{
    MyTuple h = {no<int>(1), no<double>(2.3), no<char>('4')};
    std::cout << h.get<0>().value << '\n';
    std::cout << h.get<1>().value << '\n';
    std::cout << h.get<2>().value << '\n';
}
```

And I think it's a good way to make tuples in general, even if you don't want aggregate-ness. Last time I tested, such tuples could tolerate more elements than the classic ones with the bases chained on top of each other.

Comment: Very nice! Btw, I prefer using overloaded get() function with std::in_place_index_t<I>, e.g., `get(std::in_place_index_t<I>)` instead function template with constraints.